# How To Detect Ultrasonic Waves?

Tags: java, android, fft

I am trying to develop an application which detects ultrosonic waves using microphone. These waves will be produced at a cetain frequency. So is it possible to detect these waves and their magnitude? Will noise and other hearable sounds be a big problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most consumer/audio hardware has a maximum sample rate of 44.1 kHz (48 kHz in some cases), which means that you can't use it for anything much above 20 kHz. Of course 20 kHz is "ultrasonic" for most adults, but it may well annoy children, cats and dogs.

Comment: So other answers say most phone microphones are filtering ultrasonic waves.

Comment: It's not so much the microphone (although this will almost certainly start to drop off in senstivity at higher frequencies), but the anti-aliassing filter before the A-D converter which is necessary to prevent aliassing of frequencies above Nyquist (sample rate / 2).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you'll need to make sure your microphone is capable of picking up ultrasonic-frequency noise (+20kHz).

If you have the right equipment you just need to implement a high-pass filter to cut off all frequencies below the desired starting frequency.

Answer (score 1):

detecting ultrasonic waves is no problem (it is sound after all, just a little higher), only if your hardware is able to accept those waves !

standard microphones are not sensitive to ultrasonic sounds, and microphone inputs on most hardware are filtered in the audible range (20Hz-20kHz, and often more restrictive), so the ultrasonic sound will not make it to your application.